# <T extends object>(value: T): T, but with type string where type null previously was

Tags: typescript

I'm using a tool named [pathmirror](https://github.com/werk85/pathmirror) which transforms objects like:

`{a: {b: null} }` to `{a: {b: 'a.b'}`

which is helpful for redux action names.

How can I create a typing for this?

Currently I have:

```
declare module "pathmirror" {
  export default function<T extends object>(value: T): {[key in keyof T]: object|string};
}
```

But the `object|string` does not reflect the recursivity.

Comment: So the idea is that all keys values that are not objects will now be strings ?

Comment: Does `pathmirror()` replace non-`null` properties also?  Does it accept a parameter with non-`null` properties?  What do you want to see when someone tries to call `pathmirror({a: "hey", b: {c: 123}})`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a recursive type coupled with conditional types to transform all the fields that are of primitive types to `string`, while preserving the structure of any `object` types.

The types would look like this:

```
type  StringKeysObject<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends number | string | null | undefined | boolean ? string : StringKeysObject<T[P]>;
};


function paths<T extends object>(value: T): StringKeysObject<T>{
  return null as any;
};


let dd = paths({
  a: {
    b: null
  }
})
let s = dd.a.b // string
```

Comment: Wow I didn't know that conditional types are possible. We have today holyday in germany. But I'll try tomorrow right away :D

Comment: @velop that explains why  SO is a bit of  ghost town this week :D

Comment: ok, I couldn't wait to try xD
Works like a charm. Thank you very much.